# Method that returns the product of elements in an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, product

I am stuck and if someone can point me in the right direction would be fantastic.  I have this code below and I need to add a method that returns the product of elements in the array.

```
public class ArrayProduct
{
  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    int [] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    System.out.print( "The elements are " );
    for ( int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++ )
       System.out.print( intArray[i] + " " );
    System.out.println( );

    System.out.println( "The product of all elements in the array is "
                         + arrayProduct( intArray ) );
  }

  // Insert your code here

}
```

I'm just not sure of a way to solve this without completely changing the code all together!

Comment: Q.1 How would you do this with pen and paper?

Comment: hint: see how to iterate array in java and then do the maths. as simple as that

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int arrayProduct(int[] array){
    int rtn=1;
    for(int i: array){
        rtn*=i;
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help!  I was missing the method header!

Answer (score 0):

You need a new variable in which to store the result. This variable has to be initialized with the neutral integer for multiplication.